# standard way of playing cross-mobile-platform web video

Tags: android, blackberry, video, mobile, mobile-website

I need a method of playing a video on the web for cross-mobile-platforms (iPhone, Android, Blackberry). I know that each phone has different video requirements (codec, players, screen-sizes)

My Question is How is this achieved from the web?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to upload everything to youtube -  m.youtube.com [should support](http://www.google.com/mobile/youtube/) each of those formats.

Comment: So a standard embed would do this? What about the multiple screen dimensions/sizes? Also I have reported problems with a YouTube video embed on android/blackberry devices.